# How to create bundle timeline card

Tags: google-glass, google-mirror-api

I want to create bundle timeline card. What I did so far.

Create three card and add in a list.

```
public void makeStartTimelineBundle(Credential credential) {
    List<TimelineItem> timeLineList = new ArrayList<TimelineItem>();

    TimelineItem startTimelineItem = new TimelineItem();
    TimelineItem helpTimelineItem1 = new TimelineItem();
    TimelineItem helpTimelineItem2 = new TimelineItem();

    startTimelineItem.setId("startTimelineItem");
    helpTimelineItem1.setId("helpTimelineItem1");
    helpTimelineItem2.setId("helpTimelineItem2");

    startTimelineItem.setBundleId("startCard");

    startTimelineItem.setText("startTimelineItem");
    helpTimelineItem1.setText("helpTimelineItem1");
    helpTimelineItem2.setText("helpTimelineItem2");

    timeLineList.add(startTimelineItem);
    timeLineList.add(helpTimelineItem1);
    timeLineList.add(helpTimelineItem2);

    try {
        MirrorClient.insertListTimelineItem(credential, timeLineList);
    }catch (IOException iOE) {
        log.info("Error : " + iOE);
    }
}
```

Then execute through MirrorClient

```
// list timeline
public static TimelineItem insertListTimelineItem(Credential credential,
    List<TimelineItem> items) throws IOException {

    for (TimelineItem item : items) {
        return getMirror(credential).timeline().insert(item).execute();
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I run the code in my glass I just get First timeline card.
How I create bundle of timeline card?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you're only setting the `bundleId` of one of the timeline items that you want to have in the bundle. In order to create a bundle, set **all** of the timeline items to have the same `bundleId`.

You should also not be setting the `id` of the card manually — that is generated by the Mirror API when the item is inserted.

Comment: if i do not set 'bundleId' then how mirror api understand all the timeline is in one bundle? another thing is, now it is working with same 'bundleId', with first timeline 'text'. but I set different 'text' for different timeline.